# Animation not happening as it is supposed to be for subclass of UIView with layers

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I am trying to animate a subclass of UIView that has a some layers with shadow. In a view controller, I set this view inside a container. I animate container's height constraint. The container (the purple one in the video) animates properly, but the view that is supposed to be animated, doesn't animate the way it should be.

How it looks now

[image]

This is how I animate the container view.

```
func updateWhiteCircle(with progressHeight: CGFloat?) {
    guard let progressHeight = progressHeight else {
        return
    }
    neumorphicRingProgressHeightConstraint.constant = progressHeight
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) { [weak self] in
        self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Where do I get it wrong? Why doesn't it animate the way it should be?

Comment: Can you add some more explanation of what is supposed to happen here? I can't work out what it is you want to happen

Comment: Which is the view that doesn't animate. In the code you show us, you are only updating the `progress` and from the looks of things - the `progress` ring is animation.

Comment: Yes, sorry. What should happen is: the gray circle should animate the way the purple one is, without that offset that it has.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us how you're generating the "white shadow," but likely you're setting it in the view's `layoutSubviews()` func.

The problem is, that does not animate with the size of the view.

You probably want to animate the **path** for the "shadow layer."

Here's a quick example:

```
class WhiteCircleView: UIView {
    
    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    // public vars so we can set various properties
    public var fillColor: UIColor = .white {
        didSet {
            shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    public var shadowColor: UIColor = .white {
        didSet {
            shapeLayer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    public var shadowOpacity: Float = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        }
    }
    public var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 20 {
        didSet {
            shapeLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        }
    }
    public var shadowOffset: CGSize = .zero {
        didSet {
            shapeLayer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
        }
    }
    
    public var progress: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            animCircle()
        }
    }
    private var curProgress: CGFloat = 0
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
        shapeLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let w: CGFloat = bounds.width * CGFloat(progress)
        let wi: CGFloat = (bounds.width - w) * 0.5
        let newPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds.insetBy(dx: wi, dy: wi)).cgPath
        shapeLayer.path = newPath
    }
    private func animCircle() {
        print(progress)
        let w: CGFloat = bounds.width * CGFloat(progress)
        let wi: CGFloat = (bounds.width - w) * 0.5
        let curPath = shapeLayer.path
        let newPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds.insetBy(dx: wi, dy: wi)).cgPath
        
        CATransaction.begin()
        
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        animation.fromValue = curPath
        animation.toValue = newPath
        animation.duration = 0.5
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
            // update to new path on anim end
            self.shapeLayer.path = newPath
        })
        
        shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "grow")
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}



class AnimCircleVC: UIViewController {
    
    let wcv = WhiteCircleView()
    
    let bkgColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0.75, alpha: 1.0)
    
    var progress: CGFloat = 0

    // a "center label" to show progress value
    let pLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.text = "0%"
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = bkgColor
        wcv.fillColor = bkgColor

        wcv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(wcv)
        
        pLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(pLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            wcv.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            wcv.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 200.0),
            wcv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            wcv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wcv.heightAnchor),
            
            pLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wcv.centerXAnchor),
            pLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wcv.centerYAnchor),
            pLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            pLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pLabel.widthAnchor),
        ])
        
        pLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
        pLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if progress >= 1.0 {
            // shrink it away
            progress = 0.0
        } else {
            if progress == 0.0 {
                // start at 60%
                progress = 0.6
            } else {
                // increment by 10%
                progress += 0.10
            }
        }
        // floating point can result in 0.99999...
        //  so round to 1/100th
        progress = (progress * 100).rounded() / 100.0
        wcv.progress = progress
        
        pLabel.text = "\(Int(progress * 100))%"
    }
    
}
```